# Monitoring process and restart after ending

Tags: linux, php, process

I have a Debian box, on the machine I have a php script running.

How I can monitor it, and when the php script dies, restart it automatically ?

Comment: Is it a standalone php script or part of a web site running on a webserver?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a standalone PHP script, you might be interested in [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) (by D.J. Bernstein, of QMail fame). Instead of starting services directly, the supervise daemon take care of starting those. Whenever it detects that one of the services abort for whatever reason, it attempts to restart it.

Comment: daemontools is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is also a good tool for that kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run a `cron` job every minute, and kick-off the script if it's not in the output of something like `ps aux | grep <scriptname> | grep -v grep`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duende`, of [maradns](http://www.maradns.org) fame. From [its man page](http://www.maradns.org/tutorial/man.duende.html):

> > Should the parent duende process a HUP signal, duende will restart the child process. Should the daemonized or logging process received an untrapped HUP signal or exit with an exit code of 8, duende will restart the process. Should the daemonized or logging process exit for any other reason, duende will send the logger process a TERM signal and exit. Should the duende parent process receive a TERM or INT signal, duende sends all of its children TERM signals, then exits.